# Отправление сообщения в чат принажатии на реакцию discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

У меня есть бот который генерирует embed-сообщение с реакцией, через каждых 5 минут.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на реакцию, в чат выводилось кто нажал на реакцию.

Я пытался использовать этот код, но при нажатии реакции ничего не происходило.

```
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction')
    await ctx.send(f"Пользователь: {user}, реакция {reaction.emoji}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check(arg):
    if ctx.author.id == arg.user_id:
        return str(arg.emoji) == '✅' or str(arg.emoji) == '❌'

payload = await client.wait_for('raw_reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
if str(payload.emoji) == '✅':
    await ctx.send(f"Пользователь: {user}, реакция {payload.emoji}")
```